# How to modify TabNavigation in react-native-navigation?

Tags: react-navigation

I'm using TabNavigation in react-navigation and I want to remove this (in a below image ) it is seem like borderBottom in react-navigation how to remove it ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/riyJQ.png"

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in react-navigation closed issues [issue found here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/790)
but for android it is simply setting  elevation: 0 in the navigationOptions